# Not sure where to add unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a function called `welcome_message()` that executes the `user_id_validation` function. The latter takes in the user_id entered in a tkinter entry box and validates that user_id. I am planning to conduct some unittest to test the user_id entered by the user but I'm not what to test it with.

e.g if I use `self.assertEqual(app.user_id_entry, "2319")`, it gives me an error as it doesn't even allow me to enter the user_id. Therefore None is compared to 2319. How can I fix it?

Comment: there is a conceptual error of the testing world, eiter mock some data on the unittest project database and use it.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/python-testing-with-a-mock-database-sql-68f676562461

Comment: Unit tests do not involve a human user actually inputting data. Unit tests can be run automatically as part of a test suite, with no human involvement.